# Run MySQL Query if condition is true else run another query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to split address column into streetName and streetNumber. The problem is sometimes the complete address in located in the streetName column , and sometimes too inside the streetNumber column. I am using this code to do the splitting 
    `replace(streetName, substring_index(streetName, ' ', -1), '') as 
    street,substring_index(streetName, ' ', -1) as number`

and 
    `replace(streetNumber, substring_index(streetNumber, ' ', -1), '') as 
    street,substring_index(streetNumber, ' ', -1) as number.`

What I want to do is run this section of my select query statement if streetName is null or empty execute the code with the streetNumber and vice versa.

I have to sections ifStreet() and IfStreetNumber() in a stored Procedure. But I get an error when I run it , and If I put the code directly inside the case statements it does not work as well.I get an error message, You have an error in your SQL Syntax. Is it possible to run a query base on condition or what is wrong with my approach? Thank you,

```
  SELECT 
    firstName,
    lastName,
    D.email AS email,
    streetName,
    streetNumber,
    zipCode,
    city,
    IF(length(zipCode) =5,'Germany','') As country,
    registeredOn,
    N.email AS matchedEmail,
     CASE
        WHEN gender = 'Frau' OR gender = 'f' THEN 'f'
        WHEN gender = 'Herr' OR gender = 'm' THEN 'm'
        ELSE ''
    END AS Title,
    CASE
        WHEN gender = 'Frau' OR gender = 'f' THEN 'Frau'
        WHEN gender = 'Herr' OR gender = 'm' THEN 'Herr'
        ELSE ''
    END AS Salutation,
    CASE
        WHEN streetName !='' THEN 
          call ifStreet()
    ELSE 
           call ifStreetNumber()
    END

FROM
    matchFiles.TableA AS D
        INNER JOIN
    matchFiles.TableB AS N ON D.email = N.email
WHERE
    registeredOn <= '2018-08-31';
```

Comment: There should be no problem using either `CASE` or `IF` for this. And your query already has (simple) examples of both of those. If you can't get the syntax right then maybe post an example of what isn't working. Note: you will need two CASE's or two IF's, one for street name and one for number.

Answer (score 0):

Stored Procedures are not allowed within SELECT Statements. So your approach will not work.

Try to shift your logic from your stored procedure into adequate subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I restructured the query and also dropped using a stored procedure . I using an IFNULL function to do the alternation to use either streetName or streetNumber depending on which column has a the full address string.

```
replace(IFNULL(streetName,streetNumber), substring_index(IFNULL(streetName,streetNumber), ' ', -1), '') as street,substring_index(IFNULL(streetName,streetNumber), ' ', -1) as number
```